# Is there a defined order in the triggering of onload, onerror and onloadend events?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, event-listener

I know that if I use event listeners such as `onload`, `onerror` and `onloadend` for istances of, for example, `FileReader` or `XMLHttpRequest` they will fire in sequence one after the other.

Am I **guaranteed** that the order in which the listeners resolve will have `onload`/`onerror` handlers resolve before `onloadend` or is the order random?

In other words: **can I think of `onloadend` as something similar to a `finally` statement for promises**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind the word "after":

[XMLHttpRequest: loadend event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/loadend_event)

> The loadend event is fired when a request has completed, whether successfully (after load) or unsuccessfully (after abort or error).

Can I think of onloadend as something similar to a finally statement for promises?

**Yes**